# Bash text file with two columns tab seperated grap second column and print right next to first column when match uniqe

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Example is this

```
192.168.1.1 xyz_user
192.168.5.1 ddd_user
192.168.1.1 abc_user
192.168.6.1 byd_user
```

What i need as output is this.

```
192.168.1.1 xyz_user,abc_user
192.168.5.1 ddd_user
192.168.6.1 byd_user
```

How should i approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk` tool for that:

```
awk '{ Usr[$1]= (Usr[$1]!=""?Usr[$1] "," $2: $2) }
END  { for (x in Usr) print x, Usr[x] }' infile
192.168.5.1 ddd_user
192.168.6.1 byd_user
192.168.1.1 xyz_user,abc_user
```

Here we are appending the second column value as Users of belonging to the same IP into one array value which IP is their key identifier in that array.

Ternary condition `(Usr[$1]!=""?Usr[$1] "," $2: $2)` is used to add comma between each User found for same related IP and it prevents to have a comma if value of that IP is still not set.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you output the result in the temporary file **/tmp/bashTest.txt**.

You can get your wanted result, sorted, like this:

```
for ipAddress in $( cat /tmp/bashTest.txt |awk '{print $1}' |sort -u ); do
  echo -ne "$ipAddress\t";
  for name in $( cat /tmp/bashTest.txt |grep -e "^$ipAddress" |awk '{print $2}' ); do
    echo -ne "$name,";
  done;
  echo "";
done
```

Let me know if it is enough to solve your issue.